# Method hashMapOf() in Kotlin

Tags: android, hashmap, kotlin

Can anybody please give me Concrete example of `hashMapOf()` method and when should I use it?

If i do something like this:

```
val map2 : HashMap<String, String>  = hashMapOf()
    map2["ok"] = "yes"
```

It means to initialize **map2** property I can use it.

But like other method in Kotlin for example:

```
val arr = arrayListOf<String>("1", "2", "3")
```

Is there any way I can use this method like above?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's simple:

```
val map = hashMapOf("ok" to "yes", "cancel" to "no")

print(map) // >>> {ok=yes, cancel=no}
```

Method `hashMapOf` returns `java.util.HashMap` instance with the specified key-value pairs.

*[Under the hood](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/75d80acac9f0908643bc21f18edebc18b9b1d20e/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Tuples.kt#L31-L37):*

```
/**
 * Creates a tuple of type [Pair] from this and [that].
 *
 * This can be useful for creating [Map] literals with less noise, for example:
 * @sample samples.collections.Maps.Instantiation.mapFromPairs
 */
public infix fun <A, B> A.to(that: B): Pair<A, B> = Pair(this, that)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. First example from [kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/hash-map-of.html):

```
val map: HashMap<Int, String> = hashMapOf(1 to "x", 2 to "y", -1 to "zz")
println(map) // {-1=zz, 1=x, 2=y}
```